# How to remove the first n lines from multiple files to a single output file using any windows program E.g Python

Tags: python

I use the python script below to remove the first n lines of all text files in a folder.I want the deleted lines to be sent to a single output file.
Here is my code:

```
import glob

myfiles = glob.glob("*.txt")

for file in myfiles:

  lines = open(file).readlines()

  open(file, 'w').writelines(lines[4:])
```

Comment: Python2 or Python3? This is an important distinction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not providing a full written programming answer, because there's plenty of those to be found on stackexchange if you look there. Instead here's some hints to get you to where you hopefully need to be.

First, select the lines you want (to keep) from the file after you open it.

```
for myline in lines:                # For each line, stored as myline,
                                    # It's upto you to figure out how to only do the first 4...
    mylines.append(myline)          # mylines now contains, the lines you want.

open(removed_lines, 'a').writelines(mylines) # Save the 'removed lines'.
```